# ANOVA and binomial distributions

Tags: distributions, anova, variance, binomial-distribution

I am really struggling with this question:

Given the assumptions for t-tests and ANOVAs, should data generated by a binomial process be analyzed with them?

Obviously, no. However we ran several simulations on R and found that the data can meet the normality assumption with a larger N. However, my TA is asking me if and when (what conditions) a binomial distribution meets the homogeneity of variance assumption, and I am really not sure.

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you haven't, please check the tour at https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour   I edited the question to remove 'please help me' from the title - I suppose almost all questions are looking for some kind of help.   Assuming 'TA' means this is for a course, please check https://stats.stackexchange.com/self-study/info

Comment: (1) A classical approach is to 'stabilize' variances between groups by looking at transformed data: take the square root of the arcsine of the binomial _proportions._ (2) As in the answ by @LucasFarias, the difficulty is that unequal success probabilities implies unequal variances. You might use a Welch t-test or ANOVA, for which one does not assume equal variances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a brief simulation experiment illustrating the use of the Welch
two-sample t test.

Suppose group 1 has 20 observations from $\mathsf{Binom}(10, .5)$ and
Group 2 has 20 observations from the same binomial distribution. Then
we expect testing $H_0: p_1 = p_2$ against $H_a: p_1 \ne p_2$ at the 5%
level to lead to rejection only about 5% of the time. Indeed, in one try
with suitably simulated data, we do not reject $H_0$ because the P-value
exceeds 0.05.

```
set.seed(1234)
x1 = rbinom(20, 10, .5);  x2 = rbinom(20, 10, .5)
t.test(x1, x2) 

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x1 and x2
t = 0.19661, df = 37.327, p-value = 0.8452
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.9302373  1.1302373
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
     4.85      4.75
```

Running the same experiment $B = 10^5$ times leads to rejection very nearly
5% of the time, as anticipated:

```
set.seed(215);  B = 10^5; m = 20; n = 10
pv = replicate(B, t.test(rbinom(m, n, .5), rbinom(m, n, .5))$p.val)
mean(pv <= .05)
[1] 0.04909
```

However, if $p_1 \ne p_2,$ then we would hope for a correspondingly high rejection
probability. In fact, an analogous simulation with $p_1 = .5$ and $p_2 = .7$ leads to rejection about 98% of the time.

```
set.seed(216);  B = 10^5; m = 20; n = 10
pv = replicate(B, t.test(rbinom(m, n, .5), rbinom(m, n, .7))$p.val)
mean(pv <= .05)
[1] 0.9807
```

For smaller samples with $p_1 = .5$ and $p_2 = .8,$ the power is also quite
good, with a rejection rate of about  97%.

```
set.seed(217);  B = 10^5; m = 8; n = 10
pv = replicate(B, t.test(rbinom(m, n, .5), rbinom(m, n, .8))$p.val)
mean(pv <= .05)
[1] 0.96643
```

So for the values of $p_i$ and $n_i$ used above, the Welch accommodation for unequal
variances by adjusting the degrees of freedom downward from $n_1 + n_2 - 2$ seems to be working well.

You could easily run similar experiments  for whatever parameters are relevant
in your own work.

---

*Addendum:* Here is how to use the variance-stabilizing transformation.
This example has $p_1 = p_2,$ so variances are equal and no transformation is needed, but data are the same as in my first Welch 
t test, so you can compare output directly with that. As always, a
difficulty using a transformation is to interpret the meaning of the results on the
transformed scale.

```
set.seed(1234)
x1 = rbinom(20, 10, .5);  x2 = rbinom(20, 10, .5)
y1 = sqrt(asin(x1/10)); y2 = sqrt(asin(x2/10))
t.test(y1, y2, var.eq=T)  # 2-sample POOLED t test

        Two Sample t-test

data:  y1 and y2
t = 0.14278, df = 38, p-value = 0.8872
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.08282342  0.09539338
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y  # that is means of y1 and y2
0.7051899 0.6989049
```

Also, here is a 'transformation' version of the last simulation with
small sample sizes. Power is close to the 97% obtained there.

```
set.seed(217);  B = 10^5; m = 8; n = 10
pv = replicate(B, 
  t.test( sqrt(asin(rbinom(m,n,.5)/n)), sqrt(asin(rbinom(m,n,.8)/n)) )$p.val)
mean(pv <= .05)
[1] 0.96317
```

Answer (score 0):

For a sufficiently large *n*, the gaussian approximation is a close approximation to binomial distribution.

As regards to uniform variance, when there are multiple populations involved it is safe to assume uniform variance if each binomial process in the different populations have *n* and *p* approximately equal.

See [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/256104/153349) for an explanation on equal variance.

Comment: This is right, but what matters is whether the sampling distributions of the estimates are approximately Normal, not whether the data themselves follow (conditionally) Normal distributions.  It would be interesting to have some quantitative guidance concerning how close the values of $n$ and $p$ need to be in order to work with a homoscedasticity assumption.

Comment: I have seen this rule of thumb often applied. n >= 9 * max{p/1-p,(1-p)/p} for normal approximation provided p is not close to 0 or 1. I am thinking if a simulation solution would be helpful to check homoscedasticity.

Answer (score 0):

A Binomial distribution can be represented as the sum of trials of Bernoullis. So if there are $n$ Bernoulli trials, the sum of those has a Binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p$. Where $p$ is the probability of success of the Bernoulli distribution.

Now, the variance of a Bernoulli random variable is given by $p(1-p)$, which means that, for a group of Bernoulli random variables, the variance will be homogeneous if the probability of success is the same for all of them.

Comment: This "only if" seems rather too restrictive, because it rules out many cases where ANOVA will work just fine.

Comment: @whuber you're right, I've corrected it.