# Asking about the meaning of abbreviation f(1, 78)

Tags: confidence-interval, p-value, f-distribution

[image]

Please I have a thesis defense and I wrote from this article this number f(1, 78) but I don't know what it refers to
Can anyone clear it up for ME?

THANK YOU

Comment: It's an [F-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution). The 1 and 78 are the degrees of freedom.

Comment: Some related threads: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67543/why-do-we-use-a-one-tailed-test-f-test-in-analysis-of-variance-anova and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/258461/proof-that-f-statistic-follows-f-distribution

Comment: Thank u soooooo much 

Answer (score 1):

As posted in the comments, this refers to an $F$ distribution with $1$ and $78$ degrees of freedom. In the derivation of the $F$ distribution, we divide a $\chi^2$ variable by another $\chi^2$ variable:

$$F(a, b) = \dfrac{\chi^2_a/a}{\chi^2_b/b}$$

Here, $a$ and $b$ are the degrees of freedom of the $\chi^2$ variables, and those values make their way to the $F$ distribution.

In your case, you have $F(1, 78) = F(a, b) = \dfrac{\chi^2_1/1}{\chi^2_{78}/78}$.

There are variations of this notation, such as $F_{1, 78}$, which has the same meaning.

Comment: Thank u sooo much 

Comment: @RazanNajee I’m glad to hear it! Perhaps consider upvoting and accepting this answer so future readers with similar confusion about $F$ distribution notation will know to read this.