# Are the p-values of the anova on an lme4 object one- or two-sided?

Tags: r, anova, lme4-nlme

If I run the following r code:

```
m_train = lmer(y ~ x * z + (1|x), data=data)
anova(m_train)
```

Are the resulting F statistics one-sided or two-sided?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: One sided.  The reasons are spelled out in answers to this question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67543/why-do-we-use-a-one-tailed-test-f-test-in-analysis-of-variance-anova . Although that question is about ANOVA not MLMs, the reasoning is the same.  TLDR from that: We aren't interested in the case where F is too small.